# my_strcpy gives seg fault

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* my_strcpy(char*,const char*);

int main(){
        char a[20];
        char* s = "Hello world!";
        char* d = a;
        my_strcpy(d,s);
        printf("\n d : %s \n",d);
        return 0;
}

char* my_strcpy(char* dest,const char* sour){
        if(NULL == dest || NULL == sour){
                return NULL;
        }
        while(1){
                *dest++ = *sour++;
                if(*sour == '\0'){
                        *dest = *sour;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

why do we need the char* as a return type for my_strcpy. If the d is " " it gives me a segmentation fault. If I assign it with a it works fine. Why does it give seg fault when given "".

MODIFIED : After the answers

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* my_strcpy(char*,const char*);

int main(){
        char* ret;
        char a[20];
        char* s = "Hello world!";
        char* d = "";
        ret = my_strcpy(d,s);
        if(NULL == ret){
                perror("\nret");
        }
//      printf("\n d : %s \n",d);
        return 0;
}

char* my_strcpy(char* dest,const char* sour){
        char* temp;

        if(NULL == dest || NULL == sour){
                return NULL; 
        }

        temp = dest;
        while(1){ 
                *temp++ = *sour++;
                if(*sour == '\0'){
                        *temp = *sour;
                        break;
                }
        }
        return temp;
}
```

This still gives a segfault. How to handle the condition if s="" when passed to the function strcpy.

Comment: `my_strcpy` is not returning any thing? Also do this: `if(*(dest-1) == '\0')`

Comment: You have changed your question please revert back to previous version.  `if(*sour == '\0')` was `if(*dest == '\0')`

Comment: The unexplained change confuses the new reader and one can't relate the answers to the current question

Comment: d is a char pointer you pass it to strcpy and then you try to assign it to temp and then do temp++ which is undefined when `d = ""`.

Comment: @Koushik It was `char* d = a;` before.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan according to the current question where `char * d = ""` my previous comment holds true. i dint see the edit.

Comment: Angos: You question is completely changed since I posted my answer. @Koushik yes Now I should delete answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan dont delete just modify stating the reason for modification.

Comment: The original copy algorithm was ok. Why messing it up?

Comment: @Angus you should not change question. if you want to say, You have an issue even after doing as suggested then you can say that with comments.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: My question was passing "" to the my_strcpy. I have added the null check and corrected the mistake on copying \0 to the dest

Comment: Sorry for all the confusions regarding the question. Will try to post the original question.

Comment: @Angus No problem, but from next time be-careful and take time before post question. I hope you might got your answers.

Comment: @Gangadhar: Thanks for reverting back to the original post

Comment: No matter what you change, you will not be able to copy 12 byte long source into a 1 byte long destination, not to mention that a constant string is immutable.

Comment: @Angus Most welcome...  Grijesh Chauhan your answer is helpful here. please undo delete.

Comment: As things stand now (2010-10-04 06:00:00Z — revision 7), using `s = "";` causes problems because the `*dest++ = *sour++;` line has copied the null (zero) byte and is now looking at data after the end of the string (yielding undefined behaviour). The canonical form of the loop (for your choice of variable names) is `while ((*dest++ = *sour++) != '\0') ;` with the semicolon being an empty loop body on the next line (but line breaks don't show in SO comments). This does the assignment, increments the pointers, and checks whether the assigned character was the zero byte, all in one operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:  "If the d is " " it gives me a segmentation fault."
Answer:
If you assign "" or " " to d, there will not be enough space to fit "Hello World". Moreover, a constant string if assigned to a memory page tagged as data might not allow modification.

You asked "why do we need the char* as a return type for my_strcpy" as the original strcpy I presume. 
Answer:
You do not have to. You could have void as return type. However, it makes it practical if one is to do something like this:

```
printf ("%s", strcpy (dest, sour));
```

Corrected code:

```
    while(1){
            *dest++ = *sour++;
            if(*(sour-1) == '\0'){
                    break;
            }
```

or better:

```
            while(*sour != '\0'){
                *dest++ = *sour++;
            }
           *dest = *sour;
```

Comment: constant/immutable strings cannot be modified nevertheless. He did not pass the original a, as destination whose memory can be modified

Comment: Thanks for your comment that I read right after updating my answer.

Comment: returning `char*` will help in call chaining too.

Comment: @Koushik : What is call chaining ?

Comment: @Tarik: How to handle this error condition. Do the programmer has to be cautious on what has to be passed?

Comment: @Angus something like my_strcpy(dest2,my_strcpy(dest1,src)). so on.

Comment: @Angus C is relatively low level. You have to be very careful and disciplined indeed, if you  do not want to chase  virtually untraceable bugs. Use C when required by the problem at hand (performance or other requirements that make it mandatory to use C). Otherwise, use other languages such as Java or C#.

Answer (score 2):

Correct:

```
 if(*dest == '\0'){
```

should be:

```
 if(*(dest - 1) == '\0'){
```

Note:

```
 *dest++ = *sour++;
```

is equivalent to

```
*dest = *sour;
sour++;
dest++;
```

You increments `dest` after assignment, and so you are checking `\0` at position where garbage value present as you don't initialize `a[]` -causes Undefined behaviour. Additionally you don't return after while loop.

You can simply write your function as:

```
char* my_strcpy(char* dest,const char* sour){
     if(NULL == dest || NULL == sour)
         return NULL;
    char* d = dest;
     while(*dest++ = *sour++)
        ;
     return d;
}
```

Give it a try!!

Comment: Although the while loop is confusing, it is correct. The if statement takes care of checking if a null character has been reached and copying it before breaking.

Comment: Yes `if(*(dest - 1) == '\0')` this is what OP need to change.

Comment: @Gangadhar So every this is seems correct in answer.. Thanks for your upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Here you:

1. Assign the value at *sour to *dest
2. Increment both sour and dest so now the point to the next characters
3. Test if *dest is now NUL to exit the loop

As you can see, the 3rd step reads from uninitialized memory. You should test if the value that was assigned before incrementing was NUL.

```
            *dest++ = *sour++;
            if(*dest == '\0'){
                    break;
            }
```

If the dest you pass in is a constant string like " " you get a segfault because string constants are stored in read-only memory. They cannot be modified.

Comment: I think the last part is the real problem here (at least with the edited question now) i.e. passing a const string "" and expecting it to be modified with strcpy. +1

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple version:

```
char *my_strcpy(char *d, const char *s){
  int i=0;
  while(d[i++]=*s++)
    /*done inside condition*/;
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to implement strcpy as:

```
char* my_strcpy (char* s1, const char* s2)
{
  char* return_val = s1;

  *s1 = *s2;

  while(*s2 != '\0')
  {
    s1++;
    s2++;
    *s1 = *s2;
  }

  return return_val;
}
```

Always avoid multiple ++ statements in the same expression. There is never a reason to do so and it will sooner or later give you a handful of undefined/unspecified behavior bugs.